# Route_Regex in zend framework

Tags: regex, zend-framework, zend-route

My aim was to create common route for that cases:

```
http://test.com/pages/cat_name/about
http://test.com/pages/?????/about
http://test.com/pages/about
```

....
I've wrote in bootstrap:

```
$router->addRoute("pages",new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            'pages/(\w+)/:stitle',
             array( 'controller'    =>  'pages',
                'action'    =>  'index',
                'module'    =>  'pages')));
```

but it still doesnt work. whats wrong?

Comment: define `doesn't work`.

Answer (score 0):

your code shoud be like this:

```
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':interface/:module/:controller/:action/*',
        array('interface' => 'en',
              'module' => 'pages',
              'controller' => 'pages',
              'action' => 'index'));
$router->addRoute('route_name', $route);
```

Comment: it's not what i need actually. maybe something like this will work? 'pages*/:stitle'